# A confusion on the definition of morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently read the book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by Silverman, he defines the morphism between variety $V_1$ and $V_2$ to be the rational map:
$$\phi=[\phi_0,\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_n],\text{ where }\phi_i\in K(V_1)\text{ and }\phi \text{ is regular at every points of }V_1$$

But, from the GTM 52 by Hartshorne, the morphism is defined to be a map $\phi:V_1\rightarrow V_2$, such that

1. $\phi$ is continous
2. for every regular function $f$ on an open set $U\subset V_2$, the function $f\circ \phi$ is regular on $\phi^{-1}(U)$

My question is:

> How can we show that the morphism defined by Hartshorne must have the form which defined by Silverman?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question might be Lemma I.3.6 in Hartshorne.

Comment: @Jesko yes, thank you very much. I didn't read the book carefully...